# Filter/query with nested subexpressions

Tags: elasticsearch

How would I turn queries such as

```
(((field1:value1 OR
   ((field2: value2a AND field0:value0) OR field2:value2b))
       AND (field3:value3 OR field4:value4)
       OR ((field1:value101 OR field2:value102)
 AND field100:value23)
```

into a bool query/filter?  Using `"nested"` filter doesn't seem to allow for arbitrary subexpression depths, as I am getting

```
QueryParsingException[[ptsiem] [nested] filter does not support [should]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed `and` and `or` filters in the documentation:

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-and-filter.html
- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-or-filter.html

These seem allow users to construct expressions of any depth:

```
{"or": [
    {"and": [
       {"term": {"field1": "w1"}},
       {"term": {"user": "*admin*"}}
    ]},
    {"and": [
        {"term": {"id": "100500" }},
        {"term": {"language": "symta"}},
        {"term": {"oentuh": "bwmbqjk"}}
    ]}
]}
```

Comment: Beware of performance considerations between the use  of `and`/`or`/`not` and `bool` equivalent `must`/`should`/`must_not` : there is a [nice post about it](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/). In your case, the `bool` version would be better.

Comment: @ThomasCucchietti are they also nestable, with the same performance gain?  My current goal is to translate another query language that our web interface uses into ES DSL as we move to having ES as backend, and our QL allows for arbitrary nesting of expressions, and this feature is (ab)used often.

Comment: Indeed, you can nest `bool` filters in other `bool` filters, and in `and/or/not` filters too. Check the end of the post in my previous comment, there is a section about combining these filters.